# Bounding the difference between consecutive terms in the sequence $a_n=(1+1/n)^n$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, inequality, upper-lower-bounds

I'm pretty sure the following estimate holds for $C>1$, but I can't prove it:

$$a_n:=\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n-\left(1+\frac{1}{n-1}\right)^{n-1}\leq\frac{C}{n^2}$$

For context, I was looking for some such bound in order to prove that $na_n\to0$.

I tried using the fact that

$$\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n\leq\color{red}{1}+\color{red}{1}+\color{red}{\frac{1}{2}}+\cdots+\color{red}{\frac{1}{n!}}:=S_n$$

because, by some algebra with the binomial theorem,

$$\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n=\color{red}{1}+\color{red}{1}+\color{red}{\frac{1}{2}}\color{blue}{\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)}+\cdots+\color{red}{\frac{1}{n!}}\color{blue}{\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)\cdots\left(1-\frac{n-1}{n}\right)}$$

where the blue factors are all less than one.

But I also need a good lower bound on the terms $(1+n^{-1})^{n}$, and I can't see how to pick the right lower bound to get, say,

$$a_n\leq S_n-\text{lower bound applied to the term $\left(1+\frac{1}{n-1}\right)^{n-1}$}\leq\frac{C}{n^2}$$

Comment: Compare https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3103052/42969.

Comment: @MartinR: thank you, I see the problems are related and I could use the Taylor series to find the limit of $na_n$. But I would like to calculate an explicit upper bound on $a_n$ of the form $C/n^2$, as an exercise. I still don't quite see how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $p\geq 1$. Then
$$
\left( {1 + \frac{1}{p}} \right)^p  = \exp \left( {p\log \left( {1 + \frac{1}{p}} \right)} \right) \ge \exp \left( {1 - \frac{1}{{2p}}} \right) \ge e\left( {1 - \frac{1}{{2p}}} \right)
$$
and
\begin{align*}
&\left( {1 + \frac{1}{p}} \right)^p  \le \exp \left( {p\log \left( {1 + \frac{1}{p}} \right)} \right)\le \exp \left( {1 - \left( {\frac{1}{{2p}} - \frac{1}{{3p^2 }}} \right)} \right)  \\ & \le e\left( {1 - \left( {\frac{1}{{2p}} - \frac{1}{{3p^2 }}} \right) + \frac{1}{2}\left( {\frac{1}{{2p}} - \frac{1}{{3p^2 }}} \right)^2 } \right) \le e\left( {1 - \frac{1}{{2p}} + \frac{{11}}{{24p^2 }}} \right).
\end{align*}
These inequalities follow from the fact that for all $x>0$,
$$
x - \frac{{x^2 }}{2} < \log (1 + x) < x - \frac{{x^2 }}{2} + \frac{{x^3 }}{3},\quad e^{ - x}  < 1 - x + \frac{{x^2 }}{2}.
$$
In the last step, I re-arranged the terms and observed that when multiplied by $p^2$, the sum of the terms beyond $-\frac{1}{2p}$ tend monotonically from below to $\frac{11}{24}$. Thus, for all $n\geq 2$,
\begin{align*}
\left( {1 + \frac{1}{n}} \right)^n  - \left( {1 + \frac{1}{{n - 1}}} \right)^{n - 1} & \le e - \frac{e}{{2n}} + \frac{{11}}{{24n^2 }} - e + \frac{e}{{2(n - 1)}}
\\ &
 = \frac{e}{2}\frac{1}{{n(n - 1)}} + \frac{{11}}{{24n^2 }} \le \frac{{24e + 11}}{{24}}\frac{1}{{n^2 }} < \frac{4}{{n^2 }} .
\end{align*}
**Addendum:** By the mean value theorem
\begin{align*}
&\left( {1 + \frac{1}{n}} \right)^n  - \left( {1 + \frac{1}{{n - 1}}} \right)^{n - 1}  = \left( {1 + \frac{1}{\xi }} \right)^\xi  \left( {\log \left( {1 + \frac{1}{\xi }} \right) - \frac{1}{{\xi  + 1}}} \right)
\\ &
 \le e\left( {\log \left( {1 + \frac{1}{\xi }} \right) - \frac{1}{{\xi  + 1}}} \right) \le \frac{e}{{2\xi ^2 }} \le \frac{e}{{2(n - 1)^2 }},
\end{align*}
where $n-1<\xi<n$ is a suitable number.

Comment: Thank you! The mean value theorem argument is very nice, but to use it I guess we need to know $f(x)=(1+x^{-1})^x\leq e$ for reals $x\geq 1$, not just positive integers. By L'Hopital we know $f\to e$, so we could show $f\leq e$ if we could show $f$ is everywhere increasing. From $f'$ that amounts to showing $\ln(1+x^{-1})-(x+1)^{-1}>0$, but I'm stuck there.

Comment: Never mind, now I see that $\ln(1+x^{-1})>x^{-1}>(x+1)^{-1}$ using Taylor series with remainder I think?

Comment: Your first inequality is the other way around. Note that $\log \left( {1 + \frac{1}{x}} \right) = \int_0^1 {\frac{{ds}}{{x + s}}}$ and $
\frac{1}{{x + 1}} = \int_0^1 {\frac{{ds}}{{x + 1}}}  < \int_0^1 {\frac{{ds}}{{x + s}} < \int_0^1 {\frac{{ds}}{x}} }  = \frac{1}{x}$.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

If you use Taylor series
$$b_p=\left(1+\frac{1}{p}\right)^p\implies \log(b_p)=p\log\left(1+\frac{1}{p}\right)$$
$$\log(b_p)=p\Bigg[\frac{1}{p}-\frac{1}{2 p^2}+\frac{1}{3 p^3}-\frac{1}{4
   p^4}+\frac{1}{5 p^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{p^6}\right) \Bigg]$$
$$\log(b_p)=1-\frac{1}{2 p}+\frac{1}{3 p^2}-\frac{1}{4p^3}+\frac{1}{5 p^4}+O\left(\frac{1}{p^5}\right) $$
$$b_p=e^{\log(b_p)}=e-\frac{e}{2 p}+\frac{11 e}{24 p^2}-\frac{7 e}{16
   p^3}+\frac{2447 e}{5760 p^4}+O\left(\frac{1}{p^5}\right) $$

Apply is twice and continue with Taylor series to make
$$a_n=\frac{e}{2 n^2}-\frac{5 e}{12 n^3}+\frac{7 e}{16
   n^4}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^5}\right) $$

So, to make the inequality true for all $n$, we need $C >\frac{1}{2}e$

Comment: Unless you have an explicit bound on the error term, this only proves that the inequality is true for all $n$ with *some* $C > e/2$. The question author clarified in a comment that they are looking for an *explicit* bound $C/n^2$.